# Do we have the universal property of the edge of the spectrum for the Wigner matrix?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

In Chapter 3 of the textbook: [An Introduction to Random Matrices](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiC8aL504P7AhW_k2oFHTv9BK8QFnoECBUQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il%2F%7Ezeitouni%2Fcupbook.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0wbMPwbj788zuq0QFfT4Cp&cshid=1666985383466164), we have that for normalized GUE/GOE/GSE and ordering its eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \cdots \le \lambda_n$, we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}P(n^{2/3}(\lambda_n-2)\le x)\to \mbox{Tracy-Widom law}
$$

Thereby, we have $\lambda_2-\lambda_1\approx O_p(n^{-2/3})$.

Question: Can we weaken the conditions of "GOE" (Gaussian orthogonal ensemble)? For example for any symmetric Wigner matrix ensembles with some conditions on the moment?

Here symmetric Wigner matrix ensembles mean the upper triangular coefficients $\xi_{ij}, j\ge i$ are jointly independent and real with $\xi_{ij}=\xi_{ji}$, and the strictly upper triangular coefficients will be iid, as will the diagonal coefficients, but the diagonal classes' of coefficients may have a different distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive literature on the universality of the Tracy-Widom distribution. Here are some pointers:

- [Quantitative Tracy-Widom
  laws for the largest eigenvalue of generalized Wigner matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.00546)
  studies the general case of a Wigner matrix.
- [A necessary and
  sufficient condition for edge universality at the largest singular
  values of covariance matrices](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26542349%20) considers Wishart matrices, of the
  form $XX^\ast$.
- [Local law and Tracy–Widom
  limit for sparse random matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08767) considers sparse random
  matrices.
- [Tracy-Widom distribution
  for the edge eigenvalues of Gram type random matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04166) considers
  Gram matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much!